# Looking for a reference for a result of Khinchin

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a reference other than Khinchin's Metrische Kettenbruchproblem http://www.numdam.org/item/CM_1935__1__361_0/ for the following result of Khinchin mentioned in a paper of Diamond and Vaaler (p.74)
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-122/issue-1/Estimates-for-partial-sums-of-continued-fraction-partial-quotients/pjm/1102702122.full

\begin{align}(b_1 + \cdots + b_N)/(N\log{N}) \to 1/\log{2} \end{align} in measure as $N \to \infty$, where
\begin{align} b_n = 
\begin{cases}
a_n, \text{ if } a_n < n(\log{n})^{4/3} \\\\
0, \text{ otherwise. }
\end{cases} 
\end{align}

Here, $a_n$ is the $n-th$ digit or partial quotient of the continued fraction expansion of an irrational number in $(0,1)$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in Khinchin's little book, section 16 is called Average Values. There is a footnote (by B. V. Gnedenko) that says that the results of the section are in the 1935 Compositio article. At the bottom of page 92 (Dover edition)  we see $d(1)  = \frac{ \log 4 - \log 3}{\log 2}.$  Anyway, take a look